# How difficult is it to create the functionalities found in Kissmetrics, Mixpanel and Woopra in my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, mixpanel, kissmetrics

I wish to "know every person and everything they did."

For the funnel and cohorts, I could probably use Google Analytics. But how if I want a clear overview of who a user is and a whole history of what they have done on my site.

I am working on Ruby on Rails. Is there a gem for this? Is it easy to build it from scratch?

Comment: There are many gems in Ruby for Google Analytic check here http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=google-an

Comment: Do you want to replicate the functionality from these services or just integrate them into your website?